# How can I draw a semantic differential chart in Fusionchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, line, fusioncharts

I am looking for a chart solution of an semantic differential like in this pictures.[image]

But I found only line charts like this one:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/T5C6h/)

How can I change this chart into ones like this below.

Maybe in this part?

```
        "trendlines": [
            {
                "line": [
                    {
                        "startvalue": "17022",
                        "color": "#6baa01",
                        "valueOnRight": "1",
                        "displayvalue": "Average"
                    }
                ]
            }
```